# OrderedDict(Counter(s)) will it give ordered dictionay always?

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter, ordereddictionary

I have code like the following, I want to get the order in which the keys are inserted

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
s = 'abcdabcd'
d = OrderedDict(Counter(s))
print(d)
```

output: `OrderedDict([('a', 2), ('b', 2), ('c', 2), ('d', 2)])`

Is the right way to do that, can we get same order for every time run the code?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you repeatedly run your code, it'll produce the same order *provided you use Python 3.6 or newer*.

That's because iterating over `Counter()` objects will always give you the items in *insertion* order, and that order is determined by the input. If the `s` input doesn't change, neither will the output of `OrderedDict(Counter(s))`.

Note that this is the *insertion order* of keys, not the order produced by `Counter.most_common()`; the items are not sorted when passed from `Counter()` to `OrderedDict`. The order remains stable because as of Python 3.6, the Python implementation of dictionaries was changed to use less memory, and that in turn had the side effect of the insertion order being recorded. As of Python 3.7, maintaining insertion order in dictionaries became part of the language specification. See [How to keep keys/values in same order as declared?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/how-to-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared/39537308#39537308)

So keys are listed in order of first appearance:

```
>>> from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict(Counter("aaabbc"))
OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 2), ('c', 1)])
>>> OrderedDict(Counter("abbccc"))
OrderedDict([('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)])
>>> OrderedDict(Counter("cba"))
OrderedDict([('c', 1), ('b', 1), ('a', 1)])
```

If you want to capture a different ordering, you need to sort the items before passing them to the `OrderedDict()` object. E.g. for most common ordering (highest count first), pass in the result of `Counter.most_common()`:

```
>>> s = "abbcaaacbbbbc"
>>> OrderedDict(Counter(s).most_common())
OrderedDict([('b', 6), ('a', 4), ('c', 3)])
```

If people are wondering why you still might use an `OrderedDict`: with this type you can re-order keys (via `OrderedDict.move_to_end()`). You can also use `reversed()` on an ordered dict (as well as its dictionary views).

(Note: I got this wrong on first draft, after verification I adjusted this answer).